# finite difference for a second order ode

Tags: numerical-analysis, finite-difference, differential-equations

I saw in a code for discretization of something like $\frac{d^2T(x)}{d^2x}$ , ( $x = sin(\theta)$ ) tries

```
   !============== here are some defined variables
   deltaTheta = pi/150
   deltax(i) = cos(theta(i)) * deltaTheta  
   dx = 0.5*(deltax(i) + deltax(i+1))
   dx1 = 0.5*(deltax(i-1)+ deltax(i))
   !============== here is the discretization that I am talking about
   ... = ((T(i+1) - T(i))/dx - (T(i) - T(i-1))/dx1)/(0.5 *(dx + dx1))
```

this discretization was for non-boundary cites; what does this discretization called?

Comment: Do you mean beyond being called the three point stencil? Or are you talking about the choice of grid points?

Comment: @origimbo What I don't understand are defining and usage of "dx" and "dx1"

Comment: The three points might have different separations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the computation of the second derivative from three non-equidistant points. It is computed by first computing (an approximation of) the derivatives on each of the two intervals adjacent to point $i$ using
$$
  \frac{T(i+1)-T(i)}{\Delta(i+1)}
$$
and
$$
  \frac{T(i)-T(i-1)}{\Delta(i)}
$$
and then computing (an approximation of) the second derivative by taking a finite difference stencil with regard to the midpoints of the two intervals:
$$
  \frac{
  \frac{T(i+1)-T(i)}{\Delta(i+1)}
  -
  \frac{T(i)-T(i-1)}{\Delta(i)}
  }{\frac{\Delta(i+1)+\Delta(i)}{2}}
$$
Here, $\Delta(i+1)=x(i+1)-x(i)$ and $\Delta(i)=x(i)-x(i-1)$ are the `dx1` and `dx` terms in the formula of the code you're looking at.

I have no idea how this relates to the `dx` and `dx1` variables -- these look wrong to me since they are not *increments* but averages of the `deltax(i)` which themselves are not deltas (differences) but point locations as far as I can see. I can't seem to see that this choice of variable names or expressions makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the reply, since x = sin(\theta) then dx = cos(\theta) d\theta  so detlax is really a difference; all the points that you mentioned make sense to me.

Comment: BTW, thanks for your informative website, very glad to know you.